# Text is cutting from bottom in TextView

Tags: android, layout, textview, text-size

I have create a row layout for list.i used customize textview to resize textsize.
but text is cutting from bottom at shown in highlighted area.
can anybody have a idea why it is happening.Please provide me some solution.

Comment: apply padding to textview..

Comment: fill text view height wrap content

Comment: textview height is already wrap_content

Comment: Increase the height of textview

Comment: May be you would like to provide layout? Otherwise your answers will be just guesswork.